# jQuery UI selectmenu loses title attribute

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jQuery UI selectmenu and tooltip in conjunction to create a tooltip that hovers over the selectmenu. The problem is, when you call `selectmenu()` on an element, jQuery seems to remove the title attribute which causes the tooltip to not display on that element. Calling `$('#element').attr("title", "Test")` does nothing.

How can I set the tite attribute of a jQuery selectmenu?

Comment: Please add a fiddle to understand the problem better

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want native tooltip (i.e. title) or jquery-ui tooltip? For native tooltip $('#idofyourselectelement-button').attr("title", "Mytitle"). For jquery-ui tooltip see Banana's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will not work because the select you see on your page is no longer your select list. it is a new element group created by the `.selectmenu()` and styled to look like a select.

you need to locate the new group on the page, and apply the tooltip to it. jQuery `.selectmenu()` will set the new group's id to be the same one as your select's with the suffix `"-button"`.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#number").selectmenu();
    
    $("#number-button").attr("title", "").tooltip({
        content: function () {
            return "some tooltip";
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select name="number" id="number" title="test">
    <option>1</option>
    <option selected="selected">2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.